# VBA code, Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

Apollogies, I know this has been posted hundreds of times but Ive looked at them and still cant solve this

So I have a workbook (first time using vba)
first sheet is a graph
second sheet is a sheet containing values of nodes and stress
Third sheet is a sheet containing values of nodes and stress
Etc up to 17th sheet

I have a graph plot of stress vs number in sheet 1, and it contains only data from sheet 2 "stress1" and sheet 3 "stress2"

trying to make code to add the values of stress3 to my graph in sheet 1

CODE

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(x).Name = "=""Stress3"""

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(x).Values = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stress3").Range("B9:B782")
```

Everything but the last line works, throws an error 1004 which I assume is because I have to do something to allow access to other sheets?

I have also tried

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(x).Values = "=Stressx!$B$9:$B$782"
```

as the last line, same error

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

I am an idiot for putting x=3 at the top of my code, getting it working then not paying attention and removing it

the issue is the (x)
when I removed x=3 the sheets try to grab values from sheet x
which it doesnt know what x is

fixed by readding x=3 or changing the (x) to a number